# How to test if each element of a matrix in R meets a condition?

Tags: r

Another challenge here. Suppose I have a square matrix in R and I want to test if each element of this matrix meets some condition. The result would be a matrix of the same size with TRUE and FALSE as elements. How can we do this avoiding a "for" loop? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write the condition that you want.  Here is a simple example.

```
set.seed(2018)
Mat = matrix(rnorm(25), ncol=5)

abs(Mat) > 1
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[2,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[5,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: OMG, it's so simple.... Shame on me

Comment: @coolsv as you learn R, you'll find that it is very powerful.